# Is there a JavaScript IDE supporting @augments and such?

Tags: javascript, ide

I feel frustrated, because there does not seem to be any IDE that understands JsDoc. I want to be able to do something like:

```
/**
 * @class B
 * @augments A
 */
B = A.extend({
    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor: function() {
    }
});

var instance = new B();
```

So, if I now type `instance.`, the IDE would show a code assistant with all methods found in `B` and its parents.

I have tried Eclipse, Aptana Studio, NetBeans and all have failed so far. Does anyone know an IDE that actually works for JavaScript development? I want the outline and code assistant to work, those are the most crucial features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) supports it. You can try out a 30 day trial of the latest 2.0 build (currently in testing) from http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/index.html

Edit: Just tried, and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I gave it a shot and it actually worked! Wonderful, I'll accept your answer if noone else comes up with anything better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse with  JSEclipse plugin can be useful.

http://www.interaktonline.com/products/eclipse/jseclipse/Features/Details/Contextual+code+completion.html?id_ftr=558

Comment: I never did, but my fellow collegues have and seen the code completion working, but there are problems of its own which i didnt liked. eg you cant indent code using ctrl+I etc

Comment: I will try it tomorrow, as I am starting with some big javascript work tomorrow, good excuse to me for trying this..